# Passing a shell variable from a sub-make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to pass the shell variable $$s from the sub recipe into the main one but after many attempts (tried exporting them), I still cant manage to get it. Is there any way to achieve that?

This is what I want to do:

```
.ONESHELL:
sub-recipe:
        @read s;
        @echo "$$s in sub-recipe";

main-recipe: sub-recipe
        @echo "$$s in main-recipe"
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  A recipe is run in a shell as a separate process from make, and local variables in the shell cannot be seen by make.  It's typically not a good idea to ask the user for input from a makefile anyway; in some context the recipe you run won't have stdin from the terminal (for example if you run make with the `-j` option).  If you restrict yourself to using GNU make there are some things you can do but generally I'd look for a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to *directly* communicate shell variables between recipes in GNU Make. You can however have the recipe save the variable into a file and let other recipes depend on that file:

```
ONESHELL:
sub-recipe.var:
    read s
    echo $$s > $@
main-recipe: sub-recipe.var
    cat sub-recipe.var
    echo " in main-recipe"
```